# NSUserDefaults synchronize

Tags: ios

I am using UserDefaults to store a small array on the back press of a navigation controller. The view that I am returning to will need to use that array.

I have read that you should not invoke the `synchronize` method manually for performance reasons and that NSUserDefaults will write the data periodically. However, can I be certain the array will always be updated for the view to use on back button press?

The array needs to be permantely stored as well which is why I am using NSUserDefaults

Comment: what does your array contain ?

Comment: UserDefaults is not the proper way to pass data between view controllers.

Comment: Perhaps you should see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Comment: @rmaddy this needs to be permantely stored in the app as well it is a Setting

Comment: @UmarFarooque it is just a small array of integers

Comment: You can use delegation method to pass data between controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call `synchronize()` but need to be aware of the following wrinkle it has.

> **Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic
>   synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or
>   if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though
>   you have not made any changes.**

[Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize)

In your scenarios, you should call it since you are making changes and system may not trigger the `synchronize()` method in time and your check might not be valid when coming back to the view controller on back press.

Another approach that I could suggest would be to declare a global array, maybe in `App Delegate` and set and fetch values to that.

Now when the app is about to terminate, in `applicationWillTerminate` just save this global array in user defaults, call `synchronize()` and similarly when app is about launch, fetch the values from user defaults and set the values to your global array.

This way you need to call `synchronize()` just once and you will also have latest copy of the data as well.